# Position Object always at the same distance of 2 other moving Objects?

Tags: unity, trigonometry, hinge-joint

I am making a procedural animation of a worm. I have already something working:

[image]

(the green dot is the position Target, purple and red are the Head and the Tail of the Worm)

I would like to add another dot in the center of the Worm to simulate the middle body waving up and down while Head and Tail are moving like this:

[image]

I thought that it was going to be easy using some kind of 2D joint, but I tried several and I was not able to find a good result.

I was also thinking that maybe I have to make some trigonometry to calculate the possible positions of Center:

[image]

Before I over-engineer the solution what would be your approach to solve this?

Comment: It seems your looking for inverse kinematics. Here is a video that might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqOAzn05fvk. This tutorial is for 3d but it can easily be changed for 2d.

Comment: @Simonster This helped, I'll use it if my worm becomes more complex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My final approach has been using basic trigonometry:

[image]

I have `a` and `b` I was just needing to calculate `c`:

```
void MoveCenter()
{
    float a = maxDistance / 2.0f;
    float b = Vector3.Distance(head.position, tail.position) / 2.0f;
    float c = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(a, 2.0f) - Mathf.Pow(b, 2.0f));

    Vector3 headTailCenterPosition = (head.position + tail.position) / 2.0f;
    Vector3 centerTargetPosition = new Vector3(headTailCenterPosition.x, headTailCenterPosition.y + c, headTailCenterPosition.z);

    center.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(center.position, centerTargetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The result:

[image]